# How to listen to the scroll state if scroll was available or not

Tags: flutter

i have simple listView.bulder widget and it has ScrollController()

Naturally if there was not enough items , so the scroll is not available and if there was enough items that are not visible on screen so  the scroll is available , so How could i listen to this state ..

```
  ScrollController ScrollController = ScrollController();

  chatScrollController.addListener(() {
     
  });
```

Comment: you can wrap with GestureDetector and call `onVerticalDragUpdate`.

Comment: but onVerticalDragUpdate will be called when user interacts with it .no ?

Comment: yes, only when user drag.. btw, why are you trying to listen?

Comment: there are several widgets on stack that should be appear only when the scroll is available , besides my items in list are not fixed, There are user deletions and some scaling that leads items to be fully visible on screen so there no scroll available but my widgets on stack still appear !

Comment: how about checking if the listView is scrollable or not, will it be enough for you?

Comment: How can i chick if listView is scrollable ? Can you provide any code line?

Answer (score 0):

##### What I can produce right now:

1. First-time scrolling, Widgets on the stack will appear when a scroll is available.
2. You can experiment by deleting items until it does not exceed the screen's height. (Widgets on the stack will not appear)
3. You can experiment by adding items until it exceeds the screen's height. (Widgets on the stack will appear again)

##### Here is the example code:

```dart
class MyListView2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyListView2State createState() => _MyListView2State();
}

class _MyListView2State extends State<MyListView2> {

  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  final GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();

  final List<String> items = List.generate(30, (index) => 'Item $index');

  late double maxHeightOfListView = 0;

  late double currentHeightOfListView = 0;

  late RenderBox renderBox;

  bool _isExceeded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _isExceeded = _scrollController.hasClients && _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent > 0;
      });
    });

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      renderBox = _key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
      maxHeightOfListView = currentHeightOfListView = renderBox.size.height;
      setState(() {});
    });
  
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        ListView.builder(
          key: _key,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          controller: _scrollController,
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(items[index]),
              trailing: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    items.removeAt(index);
                    setState(() {
                      currentHeightOfListView = renderBox.size.height;
                      if (currentHeightOfListView < maxHeightOfListView) {
                        _isExceeded = false;
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.remove)
                ),
            );
          },
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: Visibility(
            visible: _isExceeded,
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text('My Stack Widget')
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          child: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                items.add('New');    
                currentHeightOfListView = renderBox.size.height;
                if (currentHeightOfListView >= maxHeightOfListView) {
                  _isExceeded = true;
                }            
              });
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```